# regular expressions, arrays to string conversion

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I am trying to parse out only name and email address out of WHOIS results using the following regular expressions--which output the sought-after data into arrays. I want to convert these arrays into strings and put them into a mysql database. My database will be simple, containing first_name, last_name and email fields. I want to know which php functions I could use here. I welcome your suggestions.

```
  if (preg_match_all('/^registrant name: (.*)/im', $data, $matches))

                // Print the matches:
                {
                        echo '<pre>' .  print_r($matches, 1) .  '</pre>';

                 } else {

                 echo 'not found!</p>';
                 }  


  if (preg_match_all('/^registrant email: (.*)/im', $data, $email))

                // Print the matches:
                {
                        echo '<pre>' .  print_r($email, 1) .  '</pre>';

                 } else {

                 echo 'not found!</p>';
                 }
```

## Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Registrant Name: Dns Admin
            [1] => Dns Admin
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Registrant Email: dns-admin@google.com
            [1] => dns-admin@google.com
        )

)
```

the regex codes could be revised for brevity because the current code outputs name and email address twice.

Comment: there are WHOIS API's that will give you much cleaner data

Comment: `$matches` is a two-dimensional array - you just need to access the matched element from it. For example: `$registrant_name = $matches[0][1];`.

Comment: # Dagon can you please post them here?

Comment: i could, or you you could just ask google.